# MS Access Forms Date/Time Entry Trouble

Tags: ms-access, formatting, datetime-format, ms-access-forms

So I have a couple tables that I want to filter on their Date/Time fields. Here's a snapshot of the form controls that I'm experimenting with.

[image: Snapshot of form]

This will report will probably end up run on a monthly basis, and so the filter "Between Forms!Sorting!OldestDate and Forms!Sorting!NewestDate" will normally work fine. However, sometimes it's useful to just run it on a single day, as in the picture, in which case I need the filter to work out to "Between #M/D/YYYY 0:00:00# and #M/D/YYYY 23:59:59#". Setting up the format on the controls to actually record the time as well as the date, however, has not been working out.

I thought, first, maybe the time wasn't displaying bc my text boxes were too small, so I tried adding the bottom text box. The display in the snapshot is what I desire, however, if I click out of the text box the date disappears and only the time is displayed. It also does not display any time at all until I go in and manually add a time.

Is there a way to force the display of both the short date and the long time? Or is there a way to, say, set the default TimeValue for NewestDate to 23:59:59?

Right now the only "solution" I might have is CVDate(CDbl(Forms!Sorting!NewestDate)+0.99999) appearing multiple times in my WHERE clause, which will make things harder to keep track of or catch mistakes in.

I have vba experience, though I've never tried to use it to mask/edit a form parameter as it is passed to a query. I am using Access through MS Office Professional Plus 2019.

Comment: Are you using dynamic parameterized query? I never do that. I prefer VBA to dynamically build filter criteria and apply to form or report. Are these UNBOUND controls?

Comment: Yes, Unbound controls

Comment: Didn't answer other question. As stated, I recommend using VBA to conditionally build criteria. Does your data have time component saved?

Comment: Currently, I am referring to form controls in the query criteria as I am still building out what data I am gathering and figuring out how best to filter it.
The columns in proper date/time format do have time components (e.g.7/15/2021 7:15:23 AM). (Dates saved as strings are a different problem but they also include times.)

Answer (score 0):

First, in your query, specify as parameters:

```
[Forms]![Sorting]![OldestDate] DateTime,
[Forms]![Sorting]![NewestDate] DateTime;
```

Then you can filter on:

```
[YourDateField] >= [Forms]![Sorting]![OldestDate] And [YourDateField] < DateAdd("d", [Forms]![Sorting]![NewestDate])
```

If `[YourDateField]` is text, change that to *DateTime*. If that is not possible (it should be), use:

```
DateValue([YourDateField])
```